# Field passwordEncoder in package required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm attempting to autowire a password encoder in my service class using a configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

@Bean
fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}
```

Intellij detects @Autowired var passwordEncoder as a candidate for autowired.

```
@Service
class userServiceImpl : UserService {

@Autowired
private lateinit var passwordEncoder : PasswordEncoder
```

I know the configuration is being called because other elements of the config file are called.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field passwordEncoder in com.example.project.service.userServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
 The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score -1):

I added in a component scan annotation on my main class for the package in question and that got rid of the error

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.example.project.config")
    class myApplication
```

Comment: I think it's better just add a parent package rather than a specific package to prevent the possible future problem in your code.

Comment: since the code above does not show the problem, no one could of answered the question from the start. This should not be considered an answer and the entire question should be removed, with lack of details as reason. This shows poor research prior to asking